# How can I select one value from list

Tags: sql

I would like to select one record if there are many status.
example, if there is the same user and status A, B, C, select only record 'A'.
If there is the same user and status B, C, choose B, if there is only one status, bring that one.

```
=======================
User    Name    Status
=======================
123 |   Alice   | B
123 |   Alice   | A
123 |   Alice   | C
124 |   Mark    | C
125 |   Jonh    | B
126 |   Pate    | B
126 |   Pate    | C
```

expected RESULT

```
=======================
User    Name    Status
=======================
123 |   Alice   | A
124 |   Mark    | C
125 |   Jonh    | B
126 |   Pate    | B
```

Could anyone help to suggest?
Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You want the minimum status per user and name. "minimum status" = `min(status)`, "per user and name" = `group by user, name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group by` does what you need in that case, and it's a bit easier than analytical functions:

```
select user, name, min(status) as status
  from yourtable
  group by user, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number to select first record:

```
SELECT X.* FROM
 (
SELECT A.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER, NAME ORDER BY STATUS) RN FROM
TABLE1
) X WHERE RN = 1;
```